# How to use Cypress to assert that a HTML element has a height or width greater than a specified amount?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

This [Github thread](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1393) highlights how to use Cypress to assert an element has a specified height.

```
cy.get(mainMenu).should('have.css', 'height', '55px')
```

**How do I use Cypress to assert an element is greater than a specified height?**

For example, I want to assert that a certain HTML element always has a height greater than 100px.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cy.get(mainMenu).invoke('height').should('gte', 55)
```

invoke() - to call a jquery function on an element which is the [height](https://api.jquery.com/height/).

[gte](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_least) (aka. least) - to assert the target is equal or greater than a given value